# How to generate a pom.xml for shadowJar from gradle?

Tags: java, maven, gradle

I have a Gradle project that uses the `shadowJar` plugin to generate a jar where some dependencies are relocated and included. I want to generate a `pom.xml` in that jar.

I tried using the `maven` plugin to generate a pom file, but it uses the `compile` configuration dependencies. It should instead use the `shadow` configuration dependencies as defined by the shadow plugin.

```
apply plugin: 'maven'
task generatePomFile {
    doLast {
        pom {}.writeTo("$buildDir/pom.xml")
    }
}
```

How do I change the configuration used by the pom task from the maven plugin?